# Function displaying output prematurely

Tags: python

The following function gets a random number:

```
def random_ticket():
    ticket = randint(100, 999)
    print(ticket)
```

The following function is a contact form which uses the random number function:

```
def contact_form():
    print("We weren't able to find a solution to the problem you are having. Please fill out this short contact form and our personal technicion will contact you as soon as possible!\n")
    name = raw_input('Name: ')
    email = raw_input('Email: ')
    problem_description = raw_input('Describe your problem: ')
    print("\nThank you for filling out this contact form. You will soon be contacted through Email. Here is your ticket number: {}\n".format(random_ticket()))
```

However, the console displays the ticket number before the actual "Thanks for filling text". It's supposed to go after that text. How would I fix this?

Comment: You want to `return` the `ticket`, not `print`. You *can* still print it in your function, but that will not do what you are trying to do. You actually have to *return* the value from the function.

Comment: Thanks. This works. Post it as official.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
def random_ticket():
    ticket = randint(100, 999)
    print(ticket)
```

To this:

```
def random_ticket():
    ticket = randint(100, 999)
    return ticket
```

In the calling line:

```
print("\n... {}\n".format(random_ticket()))
```

You called the `random_ticket` function which already printed out `ticket` and returning `None`, so in addition to the already printed `ticket` you printed `None` in this line.

Answer (score 0):

you should return the value from random_ticket function

```
def random_ticket():
    ticket = random.randint(100, 999)
    return (ticket)
```

It will work as you expected